# Using keypress() to control all Vue interactions

Tags: javascript, oop, vue.js

I'm rewriting a game from Javascript/jQuery to Vue. The game does not use the mouse, everything is controlled by the keyboard.

The player uses the "up" and "down" arrows the cycle through the buttons, the "enter" key to select, and the "back" arrow to go back.

Each time the player selects an option, data is stored in a "game" array so that when the game is played, it can display the correct game and players.

So my question is, what would be the standard way to construct this in Vue?

I have read that if you are using jQuery to do DOM manipulation in a Vue project you are doing something wrong, but I don't know any other way to get keypress() to work across all pages the way it works in jQuery.

**This is how the page was currently constructed (to work with Javascript/jQuery):**

```
// this is the first page the player sees
<div class="page1">
    <div class="button button_selected" data-link="choosegame">Choose a game</div>
    <div class="button" data-link="highscores">Highscores</div>
    <div class="button" data-link="settings">Settings</div>
</div>

// if the player selects "choose a game", it shows this page:
<div class="choosegame">
    <div class="button" data-link="chooseplayers" data-options="{game:'checkers',players:'2',playersmax:'2'}">Checkers</div>
    <div class="button" data-link="chooseplayers" data-options="{game:'bingo',playersmin:'2',playersmax:'4'}">Bingo</div>
    <div class="button" data-link="chooseplayers" data-options="{game:'scrabble',players:'2',playersmax:'2'}">Scrabble</div>
</div>

// if the player selects a game (ex. checkers), it shows this page:
<div class="chooseplayers">
    <div class="button" data-link="playgame" data-options="{player:'Jimmy'}">Jimmy</div>
    <div class="button" data-link="playgame" data-options="{player:'Billy'}">Billy</div>
    <div class="button" data-link="playgame" data-options="{player:'Arnold'}">Arnold</div>
</div>

// after players are selected, it shows this page:
<div class="playgame">
    PLAYING!
</div>
```

Comment: Start here: [key modifiers](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers)

Comment: That only works with input fields.

Comment: You want to hang event handlers on the document?

Comment: You can handle key events from any element with focus. Set `tabindex="-1"` on it and `mounted() { this.$el.focus() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete example for your request. It's too big to explain everything, so ask questions if you need clarification.

Here I basically set an event listener on window object and handle it with Vue logic.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    buttons: [
      {
        'choosegame': 'Choose a game',
        'highscores': 'Highscores',
        'settings': 'Settings'
      },
      {
        'Checkers': { game: 'checkers', players: '2', playersmax: '2' },
        'Bingo': { game: 'bingo', playersmin: '2', playersmax: '4' },
        'Scrabble': { game: 'scrabble', players: '2', playersmax: '2' }
      },
      {
        'Jimmy': 'Jimmy',
        'Billy': 'Billy',
        'Arnold': 'Arnold'
      },
    ],
    page: 0, // currentPage
    selectedButton: 'choosegame',
    game: null, // chosen game and player
    player: null
  },
  methods: {
    handleKeyPress: function (e) {
      const keyCode = String(e.keyCode || e.code || e.keyIdentifier);
      if (keyCode === '13') { // enter
        if (this.page < 3) {
          if (this.page === 1) this.game = this.selectedButton;
          if (this.page === 2) this.player = this.selectedButton;
          if (this.page === 0 && this.selectedButton !== 'choosegame') {
            console.log('not implemented yet. choose a game instead');
          } else {
            this.page++;
            this.selectedButton = Object.keys(this.currentButtons)[0];
          }
        }
      } else if (keyCode === '38' || keyCode === '40') { // navigate up or down
        const buttons = this.buttons[this.page];
        const pageKeys = Object.keys(buttons);
        const currIndex = pageKeys.findIndex(key => this.selectedButton === key);
        const newIndex = (keyCode == 38) // up
          ? (currIndex === 0)
            ? pageKeys.length - 1
            : currIndex - 1
          : (keyCode == 40) // down
            ? (currIndex === (pageKeys.length - 1))
              ? 0
              : currIndex + 1
            : currIndex;
        this.selectedButton = pageKeys[newIndex]
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    currentButtons: function () {
      return this.buttons[this.page] || [] // current buttons object 
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    // add an event listener for keypress
    window.addEventListener('keypress', this.handleKeyPress)
  }
});
```

```css
.button_selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-if="page == 0">
    <div class="button"
      v-for="(button, index) in currentButtons" 
      :key="index" 
      :class="{'button_selected': index === selectedButton}">{{ button }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-if="page == 1 || page == 2">
    <div class="button"
      v-for="(button, index) in currentButtons" 
      :key="index" 
      :class="{'button_selected': index === selectedButton}">{{ index }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-if="page == 3">
    You made it here! {{ player }} gonna play {{ game }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to `this.handleKeyPress,bind(this)`. Methods are bound to the Vue during instantiation.

Comment: PERFECT!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Only thing I had to change was to change "keypress" to "keydown" because the up and down keys werent working for some reason. Thanks so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @supercoolville you're welcome, it was an interesting exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Key events can be used on any DOM element with focus. Ordinarily, that is input fields, but if you enable focus on a div (by setting its `tabindex` attribute to -1) and actually set the focus on it (or focus is on an element inside it that doesn't stop the event bubbling), it will handle keyboard events.

One approach is here: I make a keyBus; the main app sends events to the bus based on what key is pressed. The component (menu, game, whatever) gets the bus as a prop and responds to events.

Unfortunately for the snippet, key events trigger scrolling, which I think is uncatchable. You'll want to have all overflows hidden.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    keyBus: new Vue()
  },
  methods: {
    handleEnter() {
      this.keyBus.$emit('enter');
    },
    handleUp() {
      this.keyBus.$emit('up');
    },
    handleDown() {
      this.keyBus.$emit('down');
    }
  },
  components: {
    menuComponent: {
      template: '#menu-template',
      props: ['keyBus'],
      data() {
        return {
          ups: 0,
          downs: 0,
          enters: 0
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.keyBus.$on('up', () => ++this.ups);
        this.keyBus.$on('down', () => ++this.downs);
        this.keyBus.$on('enter', () => ++this.enters);
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$el.focus();
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" tabindex="-1" @keyup.enter="handleEnter" @keyup.up="handleUp" @keyup.down="handleDown">
  <menu-component :key-bus="keyBus">
  </menu-component>
</div>

<template id="menu-template">
<div>
Ups: {{ups}} <br>
Downs: {{downs}} <br>
Enters: {{enters}} <br>
</div>
</template>
```